# Structuring type declarations in a Node Express project

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

We are trying to figure out how to structure TypeScript types (mainly interfaces) in our Node Express project.

For context: Our project has a directory which contains multiple *modules*, which provide specific functionality, for example, configuration parsing and validation, startup checks, error objects etc.

Right now, after a bunch of experiments, I have arrived on some kind of conclusion, but I couldn't find any info on best practices so this is all based on guessing. My idea is as follows:

1. Types, which are required only for one specific action are to be defined just before the corresponding action. For example, an Axios call receives some kind of response body. To type the repsonse body, you define `ResponseBodyI` right before the Axios call and use it like `const res = axios.get<ResponseBodyI>(...)`.
2. Types, which are required all across a file/module, are defined in the top scope of the file (i.e. after the `import` statements).
3. Types, which are required *externally* when implementing the module are defined and exported in `types/[module].d.ts`. They are imported using `import type { InterfaceI } from 'types/[module].d.ts'`.

However, this approach has multiple issues:

- What do you do if a module has multiple files which require the interface *but* the interface is not needed outside the module? Do you export the interface from the module's `index.ts`? Do you define it in `types/`?
- Would it not be better to define ALL interfaces in one place? Under `types/` or the top scope of the module?
- What if there's an interface that is required both in the module definition *and* implementation? The module will need to import it from `types/`. Now the module uses interfaces which are defined both in the module *and* in `types/`.

Overall I'm pretty confused on what the best practice would be. I could just put all interface definitions in the global scope and not worry about importing them at all. However, this is also frowned upon and can cause conflicts.